# woocommerce variations - add post_meta to dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working with Woocommerce. the following code currently add's the variation price to the dropdown on the product page:

```
function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {
global $wpdb, $product;

$result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term'" );

$term_slug = ( !empty( $result ) ) ? $result[0] : $term;


$query = "SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
            WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE '_wholesale_price%'
                AND postmeta.meta_value = '$term_slug'
                AND products.post_parent = $product->id";

$variation_id = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

$parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $variation_id[0] );

if ( $parent > 0 ) {
    $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id[0] );
    return $term . ' (' . woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ) . ')';
}
return $term;

}
```

I would like to edit the following line:

```
return $term . ' (' . woocommerce_price( $_product->get_price() ) . ')';
```

Rather than it pulling in the price, i would like to show custom_meta which has already been saved.

I tried replacing the above with:

```
return $term . ' (' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wholesale_price', true ) . ')';
```

But it returns nothing. Does anyone know the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to solve this by doing the following:

```
return $term . ' (' .  $value['data']->variation_id, '_wholesale_price', true ) . ')';
```

Comment: Do you know where the $value variable comes from? It isn't set in your code and isn't included as a global.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data first if it's outside the loop. Try this:

```
global $post;
return $term . ' (' . get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wholesale_price', true) . ')';
```

Comment: Hi this doesnt work for the variation id. This returns the main post id.